# Snapchat API error: The start time can not be updated after the campaign or ad squad is in flight

Tags: snapchat

I am making following request for Snapchat API to stop the campaign at a specific time on the day:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://adsapi.snapchat.com/v1/adaccounts/c24c223b-9ae0-49f8-9032-1d7/campaigns' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer somethinghere' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "campaigns": [
        {
            "name": "Bundel_Web_Conversions",
            "ad_account_id": "c24c223b-9ae0-49f8-9032-1d7",
            "status": "PAUSE",
            "buy_model": "AUCTION",
            "start_time": "2023-09-05T08:37:13.244Z",
            "end_time": "2023-09-05T08:41:13.244Z",
            "id": "addab04d-2ed6-4aa8-a753-636a"
        }
    ]
}'
```

Getting following Error:

```
{
    "request_status": "ERROR",
    "request_id": "71cc108a-5c23-4296-87dd-01913cdd313b",
    "campaigns": [
        {
            "sub_request_error_reason": "Error code: E2719, message: The start time can not be updated after the campaign or ad squad is in flight. : [The start time can not be updated after the campaign or ad squad is in flight.]",
            "sub_request_status": "ERROR"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried many times to schedule the api but the error still

time format, API parameters are ok